# Send rm-command with $variable filename via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

in a bash script i try to do:

```
ssh -n $username@server2 "rm ${delete_file}"
```

but always get the error:

```
rm: missing operand
```

when I

```
> echo $delete_file
> /var/www/site/myfile.txt
```

I get the correct path.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that in your case, `$delete_file` is set on the remote host and not on your current machine?
If you want `$delete_file` to be expanded on the remote side (i.e., after ssh'ing into `server2`), you have to use single quotes:

```
ssh -n $username@server2 'rm ${delete_file}'
```

Other than that, do you set the value of `delete_file` in the same script (before ssh'ing), or before invoking your script? If latter is the case, it can't work: Variables are not propagated to scripts called by the current script/session.
You could do the following about it:

```
delete_file=<your-value> ./ssh-script
```

or:

```
delete_file=<your-value>
export delete_file
./ssh-script
```

As it turns out this last option was the problem, let me elaborate on best practices:
Better than setting environment variables would be the usage of [positional parameters](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0120.php).

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1: file to delete
delete_file=${1:?Missing parameter: which file for deletion?}
ssh -n $username@server2 "rm ${delete_file}"
```

Usage of the script is now as simple as:

```
./ssh-script <your-file-for-deletion>
```

This way, you don't have to remember which variable is exactly expected by the script when calling it - simply call the script with a positional parameter.

As a bonus, the example uses parameter expansion to check for not-set or empty parameters:

```
delete_file=${1:?Missing parameter: which file for deletion?}
```

Whenever `$1` happens to be unset or empty, the scripts exits immediately with `exit code 1` and prints given message to `stderr`.

Comment: no, sorry. variable is set on local host, and is then send via ssh to remote host

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Added additional notes about best practices.